# Joining three tables in entity framework and getting only result of first row instead of all the rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to join three table of SALES, PRODUCT and USERS.
Getting PRODUCT and USER names from DB by their id's present in 
SALES table.

The problem is: it only computes and gets result of first row of sales table.

Here is the Code.

```html
                                  
            var saleslist = (
                from sale in db.Sales
                join p in db.Products on sale.sale_id equals p.product_id
                join u in db.Users on sale.user_id equals u.user_id

                select new SalesView
                {
                    sale_id = sale.sale_id,
                    sale_amount = sale.sale_amount,
                    sale_time = sale.sale_time,
                    product_name = p.product_name,
                    user_name = u.user_first_name
                }).ToList();
          
            return View(saleslist);
```

SalesView is a model class that will be used to show the computed results in the view.

anyone can help?

Comment: Are you sure `sale.sale_id equals p.product_id` is correct? (seems like it should be something like `sale.product_idequals p.product_id`)

Comment: Oh thanks! That was the only problem.

Comment: How can I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: I have not added an answer yet :) - will do so shortly

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen. Much appreciate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join on the `Products` table is incorrect. Change

```
join p in db.Products on sale.sale_id equals p.product_id
```

to

```
join p in db.Products on sale.product_id equals p.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the right joins properties, try the following:

```
var saleslist = (
            from sale in db.Sales
            join p in db.Products on sale.sale_id equals p.product_id into temp
            from t in temp join u in db.Users on t.user_id equals u.user_id into temp2 
            from t2 in temp2
            select new SalesView
            {
                sale_id = sale.sale_id,
                sale_amount = sale.sale_amount,
                sale_time = sale.sale_time,
                product_name = t.product_name,
                user_name = t2.user_first_name
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(saleslist);
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much. That helped too.